# Why is the rate of diffusion of a gas dependent on the partial pressure of that gas, rather than the overall pressure gradient across the mixture?

Tags: thermodynamics, pressure, diffusion

I can intuitively understand that Brownian motion will gradually disperse gas molecules from an area of higher concentration to an area of lower concentration, until a uniform partial pressure is attained in the environment.

Assuming a mixture of non-interacting gases, my understanding is that partial pressure is a theoretical concept, as the kinetic energy of the particles will reach an equilibrium and the only measurable pressure is the total pressure (all particles being considered identical).

In that case, why is the partial pressure difference used to determine the rate of diffusion of a gas in a mixture across a membrane, rather than the net pressure difference.

For example, in physiology, why is the P(O2) used to determine its rate of diffusion across pulmonary capillary membranes, rather than the net pressure gradient?

Thanks.

Comment: Why do you think partial pressure is a theoretical concept. It is based on the ideal gas law which, in many instances, is a good approximation to real gas behavior.

Comment: It's an observed phenomenon.  The underlying mechanisms have to do with maximizing entropy, which happens when each specie is spread as widely as possible.  It's not simply the total pressure.

Comment: So I think, Bob D and @CarlWitthoft, that you are pointing out the crux of my confusion, which is: assuming all gas particles of (basically) all gases behave similarly, how can different gases in a mixture exert different partial pressures? I would have thought the kinetic energy spreads out equally eventually to all particles irrespective of what gas it is... My assumption must be false? I assume you can tell I'm no physicist.